# Kendo UI Parameters sent to the sort action are null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid defined using the C# MVC wrappers. When I click on a column header to sort, it appears to call the `read` action that I have defined:

```
//index.cshtml
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => ...)
    .Read(read =>
    {
        read.Action("Read", "MyData").Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("getRequestData()"));
    })

//MyDataController.cs
public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4)
```

When searching, it does not call `getRequestData` and for some reason some of the parameters are null, but some are not.

```
//MyPage.js
function getRequestData() {
    return {
        p1: $("#p1").val(),
        p2: $("#p2").val(),
        p3: $("#p3").val(),
        p4: $("#p4").val()
    };
};
```

It seems like I could use [parameterMap](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) and check the type to ensure that data is sent when sorting:

```
parameterMap: function(data, type) {
  if (type == "sort") {
    return getRequestData();
  }
}
```

But all of the examples of using `parameterMap` are when using JavaScript to define the grid and not the c# wrappers.

Should I be using `parameterMap`, and if so, how to use it if my grid is defined using the wrappers? If I cannot use `parameterMap`, is there any reason why sorting isn't sending all of the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you have to remove `()` from  `.Data("getRequestData")` and it work.

```
.Read(read =>
{
 read.Action("Read", "MyData").Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("getRequestData"));
})
```

Comment: Seems like you are correct. My `getRequestData` actually includes some parameters which I omitted from my question. So I have changed it to `.Data("function(){return getRequestData();}"))` and it seems to work. Will test a bit more and then accept your answer. Would still be interesting to know if `parameterMap` can be used from c#.

Comment: @row1 if `parameterMap ` work then let me know, and i am glad that it work's for you.